# Why is Mavericks forcing a password reset on every lock screen?

Tags: security, sleep-wake, macos, password, screen-lock

I just upgraded to Mavericks. Now, every time I wake it up from the lock screen or standby and proceed to type in my password it rejects it.

To get back in I have to select "switch user", then type in my username and the (same) password. Afterwards it requires me to set a new password and only then it lets me in.

This is, as you might imagine, very annoying. How can I get rid of this new security requirement?

Comment: Have you tried to repair permissions (using Disk Utility)?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Somewhere during the upgrade process the password policy `maxMinutesUntilChangePassword` was set to `100`. So every 100 minutes I had to reset the password...

To solve it I used the `pwpolicy` command:

```
pwpolicy -u "MyUserName" -setglobalpolicy "maxMinutesUntilChangePassword=86400"
```